# How to import picture to Photos.app with Applescript

Tags: applescript

```
set oldPath to "/Users/user/Desktop/aaaa/1110.jpg"
set thisPOSIXPath to (the POSIX path of oldPath)


set imageList to {}
copy thisPOSIXPath to the end of imageList


tell application "Photos"
    import imageList into container named "MyPictures"
end tell
```

I use the above script to import one picture to Photos, but the photos say an error "Unable to get metadata" while running. What's the matter with my script, and anyone know how to import one picture to Photos ?

**[Edit]**
I found the correct way to do this

```
set filePath to POSIX file "/Users/user/Desktop/aaaa/1110.jpg"

set imageList to {}
copy filePath to the end of imageList
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in imageList
    set this_item to item i of imageList as alias
end repeat


tell application "Photos"
    import imageList into container named "MyPictures"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos.app expects a list of alias specifiers as parameter of the import command.

`path to desktop` is the relative path to the desktop folder of the current user.
`as text` coerces the alias specifier to HFS path (colon separated).
Wrapping an object in braces `{}`coerces the object to a list.

```
set filePath to alias ((path to desktop as text) & "aaaa:1110.jpg")
tell application "Photos"
    import {filePath} into container named "MyPictures"
end tell
```